# How to use dnsmasq in another docker container as a DNS server?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, docker, docker-compose, dnsmasq

I need to create a local DNS server just for containers, for whitelist domain addresses.

dnsmasq.conf

```
port=53
domain-needed
bogus-priv
bind-interfaces
no-resolv
strict-order

server=/google.com/8.8.8.8
server=/google.com/8.8.4.4

server=/github.com/8.8.8.8
server=/github.com/8.8.4.4

server=/api.github.com/8.8.8.8
server=/api.github.com/8.8.4.4
```

docker-compose.yml

```yml
version: '3.8'

services:
    dns-server:
        restart: always
        image: strm/dnsmasq
        container_name: dnsmasq
        volumes:
        - ./dnsmasq.conf:/etc/dnsmasq.conf
        ports:
        - "53:53/udp"
        cap_add:
        - NET_ADMIN
        networks:
        - "custom-dns"
        
    test-dns:
        container_name: test-dns
        image: nginx:latest
        networks:
        - "custom-dns"
        dns: dns-server
        
networks:
    custom-dns: {}
```

I tried set **dns:** "dns-server", "127.0.0.1", "172.17.0.1" but not working, in container `test-dns` after command `curl google.com` result
`curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com`